# How to take out numbers and add them together in python

Tags: python

I want take out the numbers then add it together for example from this:

```
'a12bcd3'
```

my answer should be 6

how do I extract the numbers and add them together?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 6):

Python strings are sequences; looping over them gives you individual characters. If any character is a digit (test with [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)), turn it into an integer using [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) those:

```
total = sum(int(c) for c in inputstring if c.isdigit())
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = 'a12bcd3'
>>> sum(int(c) for c in inputstring if c.isdigit())
6
```

Comment: `sum(map(int,filter(str.isdigit,my_str)))` is a fun one too

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The more so as a 'look how clever I am' homework solution. Provided the OP can explain what it does.. :-P