# How to count vowels in python/codewrite string?

Tags: python

how to count vowels in python for example

'XaXeXUU'

should give me  the answer 4

how can i calculate this?

Comment: loop over them and count them if they are vowels

Comment: Welcome.. again!  During your last question, you received some [excellent advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433976/how-to-take-out-numbers-and-add-them-together-in-python#comment28812701_19433976) about how the question/answer process works.  Following it will really improve your SO experience.  You may also want to take the [welcome tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: vowels = 'aeiou';print (len([x in mystr if x.lower() in vowels]))

Answer (score 2):

```
my_string = 'XaXeXUU'
vowels = 'aeiou'
sum(ch in vowels for ch in my_string.lower())
```

Comment: `len(filter(lambda x:x in string.ascii_vowels,my_string))` would be better ... especially when the teacher asks him to explain whats going on

Comment: @JoranBeasley lol, confusing him won't help him learn though.

Comment: neither will just giving him a copy and paste homework answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley guess I was hoping he would take the time to understand what this actually does

Comment: hah its not very hard all you have to do is read it out loud :P ... im just jaded by people who just want the answers with no work :P (+1 all the same since you are right and maybe he will)

Answer (score 2):

```
len(my_string)-len(my_string.lower().translate(None,'aeiou'))
```